# How to separate redis database for same two app in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, key-value-store

I have two same app running on different one for demo and one for developement .and m using the redis database to store key value, how can i seperate redis database for these two different app. m using node.js for redis client. and m using this https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/ redis client.

how to seperate redis database for same app in node.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `.select(db, callback)` function in node_redis.

```
var redis = require('redis'),
db = redis.createClient();

db.select(1, function(err,res){
  // you'll want to check that the select was successful here
  // if(err) return err;
  db.set('key', 'string'); // this will be posted to database 1 rather than db 0
});
```

If you are using expressjs, you can set a development and production environment variable to automatically set which database you are using.

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express.createServer();

app.configure('development', function(){
  // development options go here
  app.set('redisdb', 5);
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  // production options here
  app.set('redisdb', 0);
});
```

Then you can make one call to `db.select()` and have the options set for `production` or `development`.

```
db.select(app.get('redisdb'), function(err,res){ // app.get will return the value you set above
  // do something here
});
```

More information on dev/production in expressjs: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration

The `node_redis` `.select(db, callback)` callback function will return OK in the second argument if the database is selected. An example of this can be seen on the [Usage](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/#usage) section of the [node_redis readme](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: how to create db in redis??

Comment: When you write "The node_redis .select() function will return OK if the database is selected", I read that I can use it in a synchronous fashion, relying on its immediate return value as an indicator that the database selection command has completed successfully. However, the function seems to operate asynchronously, returning undefined immediately. Synchronous selection would be super-convenient, though.

Comment: @sheldonh is right, if you operate 2 db ids(select 1, select 2) in one script, the 2 will be confused in asynchronouse executing, we should create 2 connections(redis.createClient()) to isolate them.

Comment: Just as a point of note, this example is not meant to use two different databases at runtime. Instead, a selection is made, depending on environment, whether to use database 5 for development only or database 0 only for production whilst running.

@diyism is correct, too. If you want to write to two database IDs, make sure you have two connections to the redis database and maintain them separately.