# How can I use an exclusive Redis data for Node.js tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, mocha.js

I have a Node.js application that uses Redis (with https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) to handle leaderboards features, I created a service that use redis exclusively to handle it, and I am testing it with Mocha + Chai.

My situation is that, I am messing developer data related to leaderboards every time that I run server tests with grunt (from yeoman angular-fullstack).

I am wondering if there is any way to use separated redis data for testing purpose, maybe a way to mock it or like I do with MongoDB data just creating a database exclusive for testing.

Comment: Further information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304955/how-to-separate-redis-database-for-same-two-app-in-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new database, like you do with mongo. Every Redis instance supports 16 databases.

The database index is the number you see at the end of a Redis URL: `redis://localhost:6379/0`.

The default database is 0 but you can change that to any number from 0-15

Each database provides a distinct keyspace, independent from the others. You can use the [select](http://redis.io/commands/select) command to change databases.